# Delete Session Data From Django Template

Tags: python, django

Basically, I want the user to be able to click a button in the template that will invoke

```
del request.session['example']
```

which is in my views.py

So maybe something like.

```
if *user has pressed button*:
   del request.session['example']

else:
   pass
```

I can't figure out how to communicate this between my template and my views

Comment: If this button can be a checkbox - check POST data on the view side. If there is no form on this page - invent new url pattern like `/user/prune/<key>` and a new view for it (with `@login_required` of course)

Answer (score 1):

*Any* interaction between the user and Django must be done via a URL and a view. In your case, you can have a form the user submits manually, or if you want it to be more seamless you can use Ajax, but either way the principle is the same: the user invokes some action that calls a view by making a request to a URL.